# Eclipse console not printing Chinese characters

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8

I have written a Java function which take a string parameter and generate a random id from it using some logic. Everything is working fine if my String contains English characters but when I pass Chinese characters, these are replaced by ???

Here is my code:

```
public static String generateId(String inputString) {
        /**
         * Split input string on the basis of white spaces
         */
        String arr[] = inputString.split(" ");
        /**
         * Change the first character of first substring to lowercase
         */
        String id = arr[0].substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + arr[0].substring(1);
        if(arr.length > 1)
        {
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            /**
             * Change the first character of remaining substrings to uppercase
             * and append to id
             */
            if(arr[i].trim().length() != 0)
            {
                id = id + arr[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + arr[i].substring(1);
            }
        }
        }
        int length = id.length();
        Random random = new Random();
        /**
         * If the length of id is less than 8 then append random digits to make
         * length equals to 8 else take a substring of length equals to 8
         */
        if (length < 8) {
            int len = 8 - length;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                sb.append((char) ('0' + random.nextInt(10)));
            }
            id = id + sb;

        } else {
            id = id.substring(0, 8);
        }
        /**
         * Append 4 digits random number to make length of id equals to 12
         * characters long
         */
        return id + String.format("%04d", random.nextInt(10000));
    }
```

Here are my outputs for different cases:

```
 System.out.println(MyClass.generateId("anyid"));
```

Output: anyid0660920

```
System.out.println(MyClass.generateId("这是标题"));
```

Output: ????14102367

how can I deal with this issue?

Comment: It works just fine, I am assuming your console is just not configured to use UTF-8 encoding. Output is: `这是标题71066391`

Comment: You get 4 `?` for 4 Unicode characters. I assume that your default charset is not able to display them and they are replaced by question marks. To go further, you should give OS, version and display type (GUI, terminal, Windows console) and their charset configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the Console encoding to `UTF-8`,

Go to `Run -> Run Configurations -> Common Tab -> Console Encoding (or just Encoding, in newer versions) -> Choose UTF - 8`.

By default it'd be Latin encoding (8859) which doesn't support Chinese.