# Eclipse doesn't Show emojis

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public void outPutFilter() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i<11 ; i++) {
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int j = 0 ; j<11 ; j++) {
            switch (battleCamp[i][j]) {
                case"S":{
                    System.out.printf("" + " ");
                    break;
                }
                case"H":{
                    System.out.printf("X" + " ");
                    break;
                }
                case"0":{
                    System.out.printf("" + " ");
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    System.out.printf(battleCamp[i][j] + " ");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

When I run the code I do not see the emojis do you know why ?
I use the utf-8 standard but still not to show me the emojis, I also tried to use unicode but it does not work the same

Comment: Either that or the font you're using on the terminal doesn't support unicode. Change font.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50371070/2834978

Comment: Those character display fine for me. Most likely your console font doesn't contain those emoji.

Comment: The console support unicode , on another project it works but not in this one